# Python lists within lists returning unexpected output

Tags: python, list

Code: (Python3)

```
l = [[[False,False]]*3]*3
l[0][0][0] = True
print(l)
```

Output:

```
[[[True, False], [True, False], [True, False]], [[True, False], [True,          False], [True, False]], [[True, False], [True, False], [True, False]]]
```

I just cant figure out why the second line of code changes every single first element instead of just l[0][0][0]. i feel like im missing something really obvious. if anybody could shed some light that would be great. Thanks :)

Comment: By doing `*3` you are creating a reference of the same object 3 times. Hence the result.

Comment: They contain the same references because they are the same literal.

Comment: ah that makes sense now. is there an easy way to get the result i want besides just using l.extend([])  in a for loop. the actual code im writing has an input N instead of the 3s